# Using CMake's fixup_bundle for bundling linux-only application

Tags: cmake, bundle

We developing some CV application, based of OpenCV, Boost, LibVLC and Caffe. Some of our customers want to deploy it on outdated(or unpopular) Linux distributions, so we must bundle all it's dependencies(and some vlc plugins), most of them can be found in any actual distro, but we have custom build of libcaffe vendored in our repo. So, now i solve it with this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -uex
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./contrib/caffe.arch32/lib/

function copy_deps {
  libs=$(LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1 /lib/ld-linux.so.2 "$1"  | cut -d" " -f 3 | sort |uniq | grep -v '^$')
  for lib in $libs
  do
    cp -un "$lib" ./bundle
  done
}

mkdir -p bundle

mkdir -p ./bundle/vlc/plugins
cp -r /usr/lib/vlc/plugins ./bundle/vlc

rm -rf ./bundle/vlc/plugins/lua
rm -rf ./bundle/vlc/plugins/gui
rm -rf ./bundle/vlc/plugins/visualization

for plugin in $(find ./bundle/vlc/plugins -name "*.so")
do
  copy_deps "$plugin"
done

copy_deps ./detector

cp /lib/ld-linux.so.2 ./bundle

cp ./detector ./bundle
cp ./config.ini ./bundle
mkdir -p ./bundle/config
cp -r ./config/nn ./bundle/config
cp -r ./config/neuron ./bundle/config

echo "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./ ./ld-linux.so.2 ./detector 2> /dev/null" > ./bundle/run.sh
chmod +x ./bundle/run.sh
zip -q -r bundle.zip bundle
```

It works fine, but only for executable build(we need shared lib too), only for x86_32 distros. We build our project with cmake, so after reading it's docs i noticed, that fixup_bundle is cmake-way for bundling. All examples and blogs about fixup_bundle is very simple, or related with OSX or Windows. So, i append my CMakeLists.txt

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
set(BUNDLE_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(BUNDLE_PATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/${BUNDLE_NAME}")
set(APPS ${BUNDLE_PATH})

list(APPEND DIRS ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/${LIBDIR} ${CAFFE_LINK_PATH} /lib/ /usr/lib)
list(APPEND LIBS)

INSTALL(CODE "
include(BundleUtilities)
fixup_bundle(\"${APPS}\" \"${LIBS}\" \"${DIRS}\")
" COMPONENT Runtime)
```

And then try to run make install, I noticed that only our custom libcaffe is bundled, no boost, no opencv, no VLC. Why? How to bundle all dependencies?

OS: Arch Linux.