# Avoid path problems at runtime when using cmake's ExternalProject_Add

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile, cmake

I'm pretty new to **cmake**, but I am stuck with an odd behaviour that I'd like to understand and overcome.

I'm creating an executable that uses the [Paho MQTT C library](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c). The content of this executable is irrelevant, let's say it just connects to a broker for now, nothing fancy.

To compile my program, I use `cmake` with a `CMakeLists.txt` file, which does a few things:

- use an ExternalProject block to pull the MQTT C lib from Github
- declare the executables and the linked libs

Here it is :

```
project(myproject)
include(ExternalProject)

########## CMAKE VERSION AND FLAGS ##########

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1 FATAL_ERROR)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

########## MQTT EXTERNAL LIB ##########

set(MQTT_BUILD_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/mqtt)
ExternalProject_Add(
    project_mqtt
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c
    GIT_TAG v1.2.0
    PREFIX ${MQTT_BUILD_DIR}
    CMAKE_ARGS "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}"
)
add_library(mqtt STATIC IMPORTED)

set(MQTT_LIB ${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/lib/libpaho-mqtt3a.1.2.0.dylib)
set_property(TARGET mqtt PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${MQTT_LIB})

add_dependencies(mqtt project_mqtt)
include_directories(${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/include)
link_directories(${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/lib)

########## EXECUTABLE ##########

add_executable(myproject ../src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myproject mqtt)
```

> Note that in the file I especially compile for Mac and I hardcoded the `.dylib` suffix but this is not a problem here

My folder structure is as follows :

```
myproject/
 -- CMakeLists.txt
 -- bin/
 -- build/
 -- src/
    - main.cpp
```

My compilation workflow is very standard : `cd build && cmake ../ && make`.

My sources are in `/src`, I build everything in `/build` and my executable is written in `/bin`. The `*.dylib` are explicitely built locally in the project folder (in `bin/lib`) since I don't want to install them in the system (*I want my project to be self-contained in a way*).

**It works well** (*I mean, it compiles*).

But when I run the program, I get a `dyld: Library not loaded: libpaho-mqtt3a.1.dylib` error.

.. which is quite "normal", because my lib has been installed in `bin/lib` and my executable searches for them in its own folder (which is `bin/`). So for instance if I run : `cd bin/lib && ../myproject` it works perfectly well.

So, now here are my questions :

1. [Philosophically,] Is it a good way of doing this ? I want to use this external lib but I don't want to include the Paho lib sources in my code obviously, so I though ExternalProject was a good way to go. It compiles the lib at compile time before compiling my project and I find the process quite handy. I looked for a "package manager" for C++ but there does not seem to be a strong consensus (*I'm looking at something like *composer* or *npm* for web apps*), so I did not go this route.
2. Why, oh why, does my executable look for the library file in its own directory `./` ? Can I change that ? Is it some *cmake* configuration that I missed ? I guess that I could just use a *cmake* custom command to copy the library file into the `/bin` folder, but this looks like a hack to me. Isn't it ?
3. To be honest, I'd like to have no "path dependencies" in my executable, it's to say that the executable, when compiled on a specific system, could be put anywhere on this system and work flawlessly afterwards. I understand that means that the compiled Paho MQTT lib should be statically *in* my executable, but I wonder how to do that (or even what that *really* means, in fact). Is it possible ?

I may miss a whole part of how the C/C++ compile and external lib workflow works but I think I'm close to something quite robust, it's just this lib path thing at runtime that I would like to properly understand and fix.

I'm really open to suggestions on this
Thanks a lot !

Comment: look into the bundle creation options for cmake.   it helps make a self-contained portable bundle.  for mac, it can actually make a .app directory as well.

Comment: I need this to be portable on any *NIX system, not only Mac. Would that work ? The literature I found on bundle creation options for cmake were specifically targeted at OSX ..

Comment: cmake has options for both "generic bundles" and actual mac .app bundles.  The "generic bundles" aren't magic directories you can click on to run like they are on a mac, but are self contained in terms of dependencies, which sounds like what you want.

Comment: Alright, yes, that sounds quite spot-on. Any link you have that explains that in details ?

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/add_executable.html that's how you make the mac bundle.   I'm not seeing the generic stuff right now, but I swear I read about it a couple months ago.  I need to log off for now but if I find it I'll try to update it when it's not 5am.

Comment: Maybe I lied to you... but check out what's going on in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36934881/using-cmakes-fixup-bundle-for-bundling-linux-only-application  even though there's no answer, it seems like the question might have a good start for you

Comment: maybe this, too: https://feralchicken.wordpress.com/2013/11/28/using-cmake-to-create-a-bundle-for-a-qt4vtkcgal-project/

Comment: Not a liar!  https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/install.html?highlight=install   see the "bundle" option to the install command.   I admit, though, I don't really understand the install process for cmake.   It's always confused me how to customize it beyond the "magic" it does by default.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that !

Comment: if you figure it out, you should post it as a self-answer to this question.